# Dot product interpretation as an area

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis, inner-products

Edit: as per the comments below, the interpretation discussed in this question only makes sense if both vectors have strictly positive coordinates.

I've been looking at the dot product between two vectors lately and tried to link the formula to the geometric interpretation. The formula reads:

$a•b = |a||b|cos(\theta)$

In two dimensions, say $a =[x_1, y_1]$, and $b =[x_2, y_2]$.

Then, on the **right-hand side**, $|b|cos(\theta)$ is just the projection of $b$ onto $a$, and this is multiplied by the length of $a$: **so this could be interpreted as an area of a rectangle** (and yes, if the projection of $b$ onto $a$ is zero, the area will be zero).

The left-hand side would evaluate as $x_1*x_2 + y_1*y_2$.

Interestingly, $x_1$ is the projection of vector "$a$" onto the x-axis, $y_1$ is the projection of vector "$a$" onto the y-axis, $x_2$ is the projection of "$b$" onto the x-axis and $y_2$ is the projection of "$b$" onto the y-axis.

So the **left-hand side** can again be viewed as a sum of two rectangle-areas (and yes, if any of the projections of the two vectors on any of the two axes will be zero, then the area will be zero).

So really, the dot product is telling us that:

**LHS**= the area of the rectangle, whose sides are the projections of the two vectors onto the x-axis PLUS the area of the rectangle whose sides are the projections of the two vectors onto the y-axis

**is equal to:**

**RHS**: the area of the rectangle whose sides are (i) the first vector's projection onto the second vector and (ii) the length of the second vector.

My question: what is the intuition for this? I.e. when I draw it or try to imagine it, I don't immediately see that the sum of the areas of the first two rectangles should equal the area of the third. Also, how would I prove that this relationship is always true.

Comment: Hmm no, I don't think so. The dot product can be zero, or negative, an area cannot. The area of the parallelogram spanned by $a$ and $b$ is given by another formula.

Comment: True, the projections cannot be negative, so the statement that $x_1$  is the projection of "a" onto the x-axis is not true if $x_1$ is negative. Let's pretend "a" and "b" have both strictly positive coordinates: then what i wrote should hold.

Comment: I still don't think so, dear friend. Take $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Their dot product is zero while the area of the square they span is $1$. Ok, you said "strictly positive"; then we can consider $(1,0.01)$ and $(0.01, 1)$; the dot product is $0.02$ while the area is very close to $1$. Still, there is some truth in your intuition. I found it explained in [this book](https://sites.google.com/site/winitzki/linalg), pag. 30. The **signed** area is a bilinear function of $a$ and $b$, like you correctly thought.

Comment: I say area **defined by the projections**. In your case (1,0), (0,1): the projection of one vector onto the other is zero (therefore LHS = 0). The projection of the first onto the y-axis is zero, and the projection of the second onto the x-axis is zero, so the RHS = 0 also. So the areas defined by the projections (as described in my question) will be zero.